# How to return a value of passed in property of generated object in c#

Tags: c#

I have a function that returns a particular type. Ex. FaxFile. In that object there are several different formats to download ex: PDF, LargeJpg, SmallJpg, etc.

I can call the download a pdf like this.

```
public FaxFile DownloadFaxPDFById(int faxId)
{
    return DownloadFaxById(faxId).Pdf;
}
```

What I am wanting to do is be able to pass in the property of the object ex. LargeJpg Format to download.

**Sudo Code**

```
public FaxFile DownloadFaxTypeById(int faxId, property)
{
   return DownloadFaxById(faxId).property;
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: why not use use switch case based on property?

Comment: You can't use delegates for this, but you can use lambdas.

Comment: @Yola Lambdas are one of the ways of creating delegates.  It's literally impossible to use lambdas *without* using delegates.

Comment: What is 'Sudo Code'? Only executable by admins? :s

Comment: Are there only `FaxFile` or do you have also something like `PDFFaxFile` or `LargeJpgFaxFile`?

Comment: @Servy thank you, i'm new to C#. In this case i think that this design could be improved to eliminate this need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to create an `enum` for this and pass it to your function.
Inside your function simple use `switch`.
This means more programming, but the usage of your function is much clearer.
This has also the benefit that you later can change the code how you obtain each format without taking care of the consumer of your function.

```
enum FaxFileType
{
    PDF,
    LargeJpg,
    SmallJpg,
    ...
}
```

```
public FaxFile DownloadFaxById(int faxId, FaxFileType faxFileType)
{
    switch (faxFileType)
    {
        case FaxFileType.PDF:
            return DownloadFaxById(faxId).PDF;
        case FaxFileType.LargeJpg:
            return DownloadFaxById(faxId).LargeJpg;
        case FaxFileType.SmallJpg:
            return DownloadFaxById(faxId).SmallJpg;
        ...
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This one appears to be the simplest solution. As this library I am using I don't think will change I should choose this.

Answer (score 2):

you can use reflection.

```
var resultObj = DownloadFaxById(faxId);
var result = resultObj.GetType().GetProperty("<propertyName>").GetValue(resultObj);
```

please note that you need to cast result to appropriate object

Comment: I would possibly choose this one if the object I had would changed

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this besides those already posted as answers is to use lambda expressions. Not sure what's the type of the downloaded object, so replace `DownloadedObjectType` with your own.

```
public FaxFile DownloadFaxTypeById(int faxId, Expression<Func<DownloadedObjectType, FaxFile>> expression) {

    if (!(expression.Body is MemberExpression)) {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid expression");
    }

    return expression.Compile().Invoke(DownloadFaxById(faxId));
}
```

You then call it as

```
DownloadFaxTypeById(faxId, obj => obj.Pdf)
```

However looks much uglier than simply calling

```
DownloadFaxTypeById(faxId).Pdf
```

Except for maybe providing you some control over what properties can the caller retrieve, limiting them to that specific return type and only those that are actually available for that type. This way for a subset of possible errors (like referencing non-existing property) you get compile time errors rather than all runtime as in cases using reflection.

Comment: I agree that `DownloadFaxTypeById(faxId).Pdf` is much simpler, would interesting to see why this is not a viable solution.

Comment: I started down this path, but I too thought it had to be simpler

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do this at the first place. Just use `DownloadFaxById(faxId).Pdf/LargeJpg/...;` in the call place or, if you don't want to expose class returned by `DownloadFaxById` either subclass or use aggregation and expose `Pdf`, `LargeJpg`, ... in this new class.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just use a switch statement for each format type you support from an enum. However if you really want to use reflection, you can so it as follows:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo();

    foo.GetType().GetProperty("MyProp").SetValue(foo, "Test");
    var val = foo.GetType().GetProperty("MyProp").GetValue(foo);

    Console.WriteLine(val);
}

public class Foo
{
    public String MyProp { get; set; }
}
```